# How to change \textsc font to small caps?

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I'm trying to change `\textsc` to produce small caps from a different font. The font `pajp` is used for the main text, but it doesn't have small caps. The font `paj` contains small caps, but I don't want to use anything else from that font.

The current and edited MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{paj}

\makeatletter
\let\scshape\relax % to avoid a warning
\DeclareRobustCommand\scshape{%
  \not@math@alphabet\scshape\relax
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\f@family}{\familydefault}=\z@
    \fontfamily{paj}%
  \fi
  \fontshape\scdefault\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% This font contains small caps that I want to use
% Shows T1/paj/m/sc is defined
\usefont{T1}{paj}{m}{sc}
\fontsize{14pt}{1em}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor (small caps)

% This font is used for everything else and doesn't contain small caps
% Shows T1/pajp/m/n is defined
% When using this \scshape and \textsc don't work
\usefont{T1}{pajp}{m}{n}
\fontsize{14pt}{1em}\selectfont
Lorem ipsum dolor (regular)\\

% Set the default family
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{pjap}
\fontfamily{\familydefault}\selectfont

% This doesn't work
%\fontfamily{pajp}\selectfont

%This is the standard small caps font:
%{\fontshape\scdefault\selectfont Small Caps}

This is the new one: {\scshape Small Caps}

This is the new one: \textsc{Small Caps}

\sffamily

Let's try \textsc{Small Caps}
\end{document}
```

The first image is from the MWE as above. It works. The second image is produced if I use commented out `\usefont{T1}{pajp}{m}{n}` or `\fontfamily{pajp}\selectfont` to select the regular font. It doesn't have the correct font as the small caps one.

[image: Working]
[image: Non working]

In the latter case the error messages are:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/pajp/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/pajp/m/n' instead on input line 41.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/pajp/m/sc' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/pajp/m/n' instead on input line 43.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The replacement text of `\scdefault` should be a string good for the fourth argument to `\usefont`; its default value is `sc`. Your `paj` is a family name.

Redefine `\scshape`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\scshape\relax % to avoid a warning
\DeclareRobustCommand\scshape{%
  \not@math@alphabet\scshape\relax
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\f@family}{\familydefault}=\z@
    \fontfamily{qbk}%
  \fi
  \fontshape\scdefault\selectfont}
\makeatother
```

This requires the package `pdftexcmds`.

With the redefinition `\scshape`, in a serif font context will be the same as

```
\usefont{<current encoding>}{paj}{<current weight>}{sc}
```

Complete code, where some visually clashing fonts are used just by way of example; use your favorite fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{qag} % TeX Gyre Adventor has small caps

\makeatletter
\let\scshape\relax % to avoid a warning
\DeclareRobustCommand\scshape{%
  \not@math@alphabet\scshape\relax
  \ifnum\pdf@strcmp{\f@family}{\familydefault}=\z@
    \fontfamily{qbk}%
  \fi
  \fontshape\scdefault\selectfont}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is the standard small caps font: 
{\fontshape\scdefault\selectfont Small Caps}

This is the new one: {\scshape Small Caps}

This is the new one: \textsc{Small Caps}

\sffamily

Let's try \textsc{Small Caps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For assigning the font used by `\section`, use `sectsty` or `titlesec` (there are several questions on the site dealing with the problem).

Comment: This works if both the regular font (The parts starting with word This) and the other font with new small caps contain small caps. If I change the regular one to a font that doesn't have them then the other font that contains small caps doesn't work.

Comment: @karu Of course, if a font family doesn't have small caps, the substitution rules prevail.

Comment: I have two fonts. One without small caps for the bulk of the document and the other that has the small caps I want. How do I make either the substitution rules work or solve the matter otherwise?

Comment: @karu Isn't mine the solution based on the information you gave? Set `\familydefault` to `pajp` and in the redefinition of `\scshape` use `paj` where I used `qbk`.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect your answer.

Comment: @egreg This solution worked fab for me in Debian texlive-full (2018.20190227-2) but now  in texlive-full (2020.20210202-3) is no longer working. Now it always show the font witouth scshape capabilities. So it doesnt show the small caps... Should I start a new question? Thanks

Comment: @GeorgeG. You have to wrap `\DeclareRobustCommand{\scshape}{...}` in `\AtBeginDocument{...}`

Comment: Thank you! @egreg It worked. That's amazing! Very much appreciated! Best regards.